# git diff show all files except paths specified

Tags: git

Is there a way to do `git diff -- PATH_OF_FILES_TO_NOT_DIFF`

similar to `grep -v` where you basically show everything EXCEPT what is specified in the path.

Comment: Looks like you're confusing two concepts. What you are asking about is generating a diff of a set of files, except some you want to ignore. Your comparison to `grep` is something completely different - `grep -v` prints every line in a file that doesn't match a pattern, not "everything EXCEPT what is specified in the path"... You might be looking for the `-diff` attribute you can specify in your `.gitattributes` file for specific files, though...

Comment: I know they are different concepts I was just trying to give an example to make it more clear. I know I can do regular files, but I want to match everything EXCEPT certain paths/files

Answer (score 0):

`git diff previous_release current_release !(spec)` if you've enabled extglob